# Can the Dirac Hamiltonian accommodate a variable speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, refraction, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

The Dirac Hamiltonian has the form[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation)
$$\left[\beta m c^2+c\sum_{n=1}^3\alpha_np_n\right]$$
where $\alpha_n$ and $\beta$ are Hermitian matrices, and $c$ is the speed of light.

My question: Is there a version of the Dirac Hamiltonian with a variable speed of light $c(\mathbf{r})$? When I expand the naive expression

$$\left[\beta m c^2(\mathbf{r})+c(\mathbf{r})\sum_{n=1}^3\alpha_np_n\right]$$

using a finite difference scheme, the $c^2(\mathbf{r})$ term doesn't break Hermiticity, but the $c(\mathbf{r})$ term does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $c(r)$ does not commute with $p$; the usual prescription is to replace this term with the symmetrized one:

$$ c(r) \alpha \cdot p \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \{c(r), \alpha \cdot p\} = \frac{c \alpha\cdot p + \alpha \cdot p c}{2}$$

which is manifestly hermitian